# this.submit is not triggering GET call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why isn't the call

```
this.submit()
```

not triggering a submit and calling my controller?
The dev tools in Chrome says there is an error and that the function doesn't exist!

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('SearchQuery').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert("Location found: " + results[0].geometry.location);
            $(this).submit();

        }
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchQuery, new { @class = "form-control"}) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchQuery, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitude, "", new { @class = "text-danger"
  }) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield form-control" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @Html.Hidden("latitude", Model.Latitude) @Html.Hidden("longitude",
  Model.Longitude)
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submitSearch" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
}
```

Comment: how is the form created... what is the `method` specified

Comment: Where is the html form? Please display all **relevant** source code.

Comment: Try changing it to `$(this).submit();`

Comment: $(this).submit() doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Ah, new code. After `e.preventDefault();`, add the line `myForm = $(this)`. Then change `$(this).submit();` to `myForm.submit();`

Comment: this still creates an infinite loop[ that calls the jquery submit over and over...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `$(this).submit()` is not referring to your form. Your inside another function associated with `geocoder` so your trying to call the `.submit()` function of `geocoder` which does not exist.

Even if you saved the form element to a variable, it would create an endless loop. Inside that function you first cancel the submit. Then your call the function again, cancel it again, call the function again, cancel it again, and so on and so on until the browser spits the dummy.

Instead, perform your logic first, then if you want to prevent the form submitting, cancel it (and if you don't cancel it, it will do a normal submit)

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = $('#SearchQuery').val();
  var caSubmit = true; // assume we can
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      canSubmit = false; // signal we should not submit
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
  return canSubmit; // if its false, the submit will be cancelled
});
```