# Client side validation with asp.net mvc stopped working after I added a jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Client side validation is fine in my form without the javascript click event code below. I'm doing a 'Required' check on SearchQuery and ClassDate and client side validation is fine. But when I add the jQuery click event validation stops working for 'SearchQuery' or 'ClassDate' and I get a page error

If I simply comment out this click event the validation works fine again!

Here is my JavaScript including what I've tried to do to get validation working again, but had no luck. It seems like .valid() is always true!

```js
$("#submitSearch").click(function(event) {
  //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
    $('form').validate(
    {
        rules:
        {
            SearchQuery: { required: true },
            ClassDate: { required: true }
        },
        messages:
        {
            SearchQuery: { required: "Required" },
            ClassDate: { required: "Required" }
        }
    });
    //var v = $('form').validate();
    var t = $('form').valid();
    if (!$('form').valid()) {
        return;
    }
  event.preventDefault(); // this stops the submit until we have some location data

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = document.getElementById('SearchQuery').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      //alert("Location found: " + results[0].geometry.location);

      $("#latitude").val(results[0].geometry.location.G);
      $("#longitude").val(results[0].geometry.location.K);
    }
    $("form").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchQuery, new { @class = "form-control"}) 
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchQuery, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield
  form-control" }) 
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
  @Html.Hidden("latitude", Model.Latitude) 
  @Html.Hidden("longitude", Model.Longitude)
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submitSearch" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
}
```

Here is my viewmodel that has the 'Required' attribute.

```
public class YogaSpaceListViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Location]
    [DisplayName("Location")]
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ClassDate { get; set; }

    public IPagedList<YogaSpaceResults> YogaSpaces { get; set; }

    public string LocationResults { get; set; }

    public string CenteredLocation { get; set; }

    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I click submit with no text in 'SearchQuery' I get a server error message

Comment: it says  "server error in '/' Application The resource cannot be found. Http 404. Tried posting a pic but I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: If you using jquery.validate.unobtrusive, then remove the `$('form').validate(... )` and the rules inside it

Comment: I removed the click handler and put in a submit handler and it brought back the validation. So I'm going to do that...

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$('form').validate(
    {
        rules:
        {
            SearchQuery: { required: true },
            ClassDate: { required: true }
        },
        messages:
        {
            SearchQuery: { required: "Required" },
            ClassDate: { required: "Required" }
        }
    });
```

have to be outside the definition of the button click event

Answer (score -1):

I replaced

```
$("#submitSearch").click(function(event)
```

with

```
$('form').submit()
```

and now validation is working again. I guess validation gets turned off with a click event. Or just doesn't work with it.

Comment: Your not understanding whats going on here. If your using unobtrusive client side validation, the rules are already added. Trying to add them again makes it all fail. And changing it to `$('form').submit()` will also fail since the method itself calls `$('form').submit()` so you will get an endless loop. I assume this is a school project because I have already answered this exact issue for other users. I will find it and add a link a bit later

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977951/this-submit-is-not-triggering-get-call/31978434#31978434) and the comments in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978514/trying-to-get-my-html-validationmessagefor-to-trigger-on-hidden-field-in-jquery#31978514)

Comment: Given this answer in the link how would I wait for the geocode async results to come back before returning true or false from the submit handler?

Comment: No familiar with geocode, but the `canSubmit = false;` line is inside the functions call back, which means it has completed and the results are returned - that's the points of the `results` and `status` parameters - they are populated with the values as a result of the function completing